# DependsOnGroups Fails with cyclic dependencies exception

Tags: java, testng

I'm currently writing integration test where i have to check some conditions before my tests can run.

```
public class TheClassWhichContainsIT {

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = { "init" })
    public void thisIsTheFirstTest() {
        System.out.printf("Test");
    }

    @Test(groups = "init")
    public void checkIfWeAreOnWindows() {
        throw new SkipException("Not on windows");
    }

}
```

The above example works as expected if the SkipException is thrown than the tests will be marked as skipped and not a failed as i like it.

So based on [Cedric Beust's blog](http://beust.com/weblog/2004/08/19/dependent-test-methods/) i want to refactor my integration tests into the following:

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "init" })
public class TheClassWhichContainsIT extends IntegrationTestBase {

    public void thisIsTheFirstTest() {
        System.out.printf("Test");
    }
}

@Test(groups = "init")
public class IntegrationTestBase {

    public void checkIfWeAreOnWindows() {
        throw new SkipException("ignore");
    }

}
```

But if i try to run my tests i got the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
16:test (default-test) on project testngtest: Execution default-test of goal org
.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test failed: There was an error
 in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] The following methods have cyclic dependencies:
[ERROR] TheClassWhichContainsTest.thisIsTheFirstTest()[pri:0, instance:de.akdb.k
m.tests.TheClassWhichContainsTest@3603820e]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.Graph.topologicalSort(Graph.java:148)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.topologicalSort(MethodHelper.java:26
1)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.sortMethods(MethodHelper.java:317)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.collectAndOrderMethods(MethodHelper.
java:59)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:481)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRu
nner.java:522)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.ja
va:91)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSing
leClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(Tes
tNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider
.java:113)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameCla
ssLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(Fork
edBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:
103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutio
nException
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you had problem in testng configuration file

For example if you had testng configuration like this one:

```
<test name="some-tests" preserve-order="true">
    <groups>
        <define name="test-group">
            <include name="init"/>
        </define>
        <run>
            <include name="test-group"/>
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class name="TheClassWhichContainsIT"/>
        <class name="IntegrationTestBase"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Property `preserve-order="true"` means that all classes defined in the tag `classes` will be executed in the defined order.

In this case we could receive cyclic dependency and as result error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `extends IntegrationTestBase`, and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please add a little explanation why it will work then?